# Flutter Flavors: Conditional Asset Bundling by Flavor shows "Assets Must Be File Paths" Error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am having an issue while implementing conditional asset bundling based on flavors in my Flutter app. I am following the official Flutter docs, and I'm getting an error in the YAML, and it is not mapping asset paths.

What I'm Trying to Achieve:
Conditional bundling of assets based on app flavors (e.g., free, premium), to prevent bloating the app bundle with unused assets. According to the Flutter documentation, my pubspec.yaml configuration looks like this:

yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/common/
    - path: assets/free/
      flavors:
        - free
    - path: assets/premium/
      flavors:
        - premium
```

It shows in linter:

```
Assets are required to be file paths (strings).
Try converting the value to be a string.
```

I can see the flavor is correct.

```
  const String? appFlavor = String.fromEnvironment('FLUTTER_APP_FLAVOR') != '' ? String.fromEnvironment('FLUTTER_APP_FLAVOR') : null;

  print('appFlavor: $appFlavor');
```

When I run the code with the linter warning, I get an error that the image is not found.

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "/assets/premium/test.png".
Exception: Asset not found
```